# Summation of inverse of non-zero elements in array using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to obtain a new matrix which calculates the sum of inverse of non-zero elements of each row. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,0],[4,0,6],[0,8,9]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[(1/1) + (1/2),
(1/4)+(1/6),
(1/8)+(1/9)]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
result = np.divide(1, A, where=A != 0).sum(1)
```

The result is:

```
array([1.5       , 0.41666667, 0.23611111])
```

Details:

```
np.divide(1, A, where=A != 0)
```

computes "conditional" inverse of each element.

Actually `1 / A` (for each element) is computed only for elements != 0.

And the last step is to sum this intermediate result by each row.